# Sorting Table using usort

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, drupal

I'm creating a custom module on Drupal 8. The module uses Bootstrap 3 to display a table of files which are located in a folder.

Since the files are being transferred via FTP they aren't being registered in Drupal's database.

The filenames of these PDFs contain the date we want to display and sort by. I created the following code below that strips and than combines the filenames into an actual date.

Currently I'm using `usort` to sort the array by descending order. All this works perfectly.

What I'm trying to do is make the table sortable by date. So I want to add a toggle next to the date header allowing the user to sort by descending and ascending

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/sort/

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4

```
class PDFController extends ControllerBase  {
  /**
   * Generatetable.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Return Hello string.
   */
    public function pdf(){

        // Header
        $header = [
            'date' => t('Date'),
            'fileName' => t('File Name'),
        ];

        //Getting path of PDF Uploads folder
        $newPath = $upDir . '/sites/default/files/PDF/*.*';


        //Setting empty array for $rows
        $rows = array();

        foreach(glob($newPath) as $file) {

            $textBare = $string = substr($without_extension,0,8);

            $month = substr($textBare , 2, -4);
            $day = substr($textBare , 4, -2);
            $year = substr($textBare , 6);

            $date = $month . '/' . $day . '/' . $year;

            $newDate = strtotime($date);
            $formatedDate = date('M/d/Y', $newDate);
            //print_r($formatedDate);

            $rows[] = [
                'date' => $date,
                'fileName' =>  $link,
            ];


        }

        //var_dump($rows);

        // Sorting array by time (DESC ORDER)
        usort($rows, function($firstItem, $secondItem) {
            $timeStamp1 = strtotime($firstItem['date']);
            $timeStamp2 = strtotime($secondItem['date']);
            return $timeStamp2 - $timeStamp1;
        });


        // Create the table as a render array.
        $content[] = [
            '#theme' => 'table',
            '#header' => $header,
            '#rows' => $rows,
            '#empty' =>t('Not Found'),
            '#attributes' => array (
                'class' => array('table'),
            ),
        ];

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: The link you provide shows how to do it... What is your question?

Comment: @2pha I'm having trouble understanding how to implement. Merry Christmas btw..

Comment: merry xmas... it seems that sortable datatables is not part of bootstrap 3, so you will need to include it. So you are going to need to create your own library as part of your module. The files to include in your library can be included from a cdn as in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). See this page on how to [create a library and include cdn files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module#external). You would then also have to call `$(".table').DataTable()`.